# iOS Notification Preventing Input on top half of the screen (landscape)

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app that can take input on the whole screen, it is a game and some players like to use the top part of the screen for input (or just above the middle).

Now this game runs in landscape mode and the issue is, that when a iOS Notification is received on the device (Message, another app Notification etc), input ceases to be passed to the game from the top half of the screen. Input works on the bottom half perfectly fine. Input is returned on the top half once the notification disappears.

My question is: 
Does anyone know how how to continue to receive the input touches and pass them down. Is there a setting to disable notifications interrupting the game? (I don't think so).

Is this something I should bring up with Apple?